# Performance Data from Application Insights in Visual Studio Load Test project

Tags: visual-studio, azure-devops, azure-application-insights

I have configured a Load Test project in Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise and I'm trying to add Performance Data from Application Insights so we can have more data on what's happening with the application at the time of the test. So when I right click on the Run Settings:
[image: Trying to add Performance data from Application Insights]

After I click that:

[image: No AI available in VSTS]

Please note that we have Azure services and Visual Studio Team Services. Although I'm not the one administrating these I can still recommend what to do or I might request and get permissions, but I'm not sure what to request!

The API .NET project already has Application Insights integration, but I don't know how to read that data in the Load Test project.

What are we missing?

Comment: Hi Hasan, any update on this？

Answer (score 0):

First, please make sure you have configured multiple instances of Application Insights from within the azure portal. When you use the load testing to add an application it would goes to the configured vsts account and try to connect.

Please manually add the application insight to your application and try again. Take a look at below tutorials, which should be helpful:

- [What is Application Insights?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-overview)
- [Application Insights: Frequently Asked Questions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-troubleshoot-faq)
- [Set up Application Insights for your ASP.NET website](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-asp-net)
- [Troubleshooting no data - Application Insights for .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-asp-net-troubleshoot-no-data)

Comment: When I login to Azure using my active directory credentials, I don't see any Application Insights instances. Is that the reason I don't see it in the load testing too? I'm not sure what permission I should ask for